# How to find what is the status(running or not) of the music(or audio) in C# silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if another audio is playing in background? (Windows Phone 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034205/how-to-detect-if-another-audio-is-playing-in-background-windows-phone-7)

I am developing an application for windows phone 7. The app has music in it. If there is a song being played in the background when the app is opened. I have to ask the user if he wants to stop the music he's playing because now this app starts playing music. How to find it out in visual studio c# silverlight?