# Windows Phone Multiple Background Music

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am playing continues background music in my app in Windows Phone. From the microsoft certification point of view the parallel sound must not be opened if there is already music being played.

What should I do?

Should I:

1. Detect any background music like song and prompt to user to stop my app background 
   OR
2. Detect any background music and prompt to user to stop already played music in the background like any song?
   OR
3. Can I can play both backgrounds at the same time with the user's permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if background music is playing in WP8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734071/how-to-detect-if-background-music-is-playing-in-wp8)

Comment: I want to be more specific.... and want to choose one of three cases so that my app could not get rejected fourth time.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like options 1 and 2 are just a single choice you can present to the user: "My audio or your existing audio".

However the very fact you start playing audio will very likely stop any background audio. So you must go with option 2.

Who would honestly pick the 3rd option?

Comment: Yes.. you are right... But which option(1 Or 2) should I choose from the microsoft cerfication point of view???

Comment: Looking at this more closely you must go with option 2. Answer updated.