# Windows Phone music player app plays songs from phone library

Tags: windows-phone-8, media-player, media-library, background-agent

Im learning windows phone 8 development recently. And started developing music player that plays from phone library. I used MediaLibrary API to get all songs,albums and its working fine now.

What is the problme now is i've assigned MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged,and MediaPlayer_ActiveSongChanged to mediaplayer object. It triggers when i change the songs that are displayed in longListSelector. That events are not firing when i press next or prev button that i get when I press volume button.

Hope You understood what is the problem.
I tried using backgroundPlayerAgent and got to know that doesn support MediaLibrary.
And I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036057/windows-phone-how-to-listen-to-volume-muisc-control-events) question also. But i saw few apps that are able to listen to those prev/next button events. If you know what am i missing please help?? Is there any other third party libraries available?? I've searched lot in web but i dint get any usefull information. SO posting this question thinking that i might get some information

Comment: Is that BackgroundAudioPlayer you've used or what? Did you try [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-Player-b5f70b13) sample from msdn!

Comment: Ya i've tried that. But BackgroundAudioPlayer doesnt take SongCollection.

Comment: SongCollection in the sense? You mean a a LIst?

Comment: SongCollection is collection of objects of type Song. That I'll get from this code MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
           SongCollection _Songs = library.Songs;

Comment: Just check this thread which addresses the same problem with the SOngCollection: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7eab9a96-0107-4453-aa76-30adbb281ebb/backgroundaudioplayer-and-medialibrary-integration?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Ya i've gone through that too.. They say its not possible to integrate :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Settings > Music`
2. Search for `Filter audio files`
3. set audio files By Size....

You will get all songs then

Comment: Please read the question again if you dont understand, your answer is not at all related to my question